# $\phi^4$-Theory: Sub-Diagram zero $\Rightarrow$ Diagram zero?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Considering a bosonic $\phi^4$-theory:

If I know that a certain connected Feynman diagram has a vanishing contribution. Does this imply that all larger connected diagrams containing this diagram are also vanishing in the general case?

In my specific problem, all diagrams contributing to the self-energy are zero. Is the implication true for this case?

A simple example would be: If the order one tadpole diagram and larger diagrams containing this tadpole diagram.

Comment: By 'vanishing contribution' do you mean it is identically zero, or just that it doesn't have divergent terms? Which regularization scheme do you use?

Comment: I mean identically zero. The whole consideration is for the description of phase transitions with a momentum cutoff $0<k<\Lambda$.

Comment: So you are asking _What is (the integral of) a function times the zero-function?_

Comment: @Qmechanic is the argumentation of your statement the following: 
One can first integrate the vertices of the subdiagram, which leads to the 'zero-function' per definition of my problem as the subdiagram is zero. This leads to the whole diagram vanishing. - If this argumentation is applicable my question would be somehow trivially answered by 'yes'

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.